# Somewhat simple PHP array intersection question

Tags: php, arrays, key, intersection

Maybe I'm going insane, but I could have sworn that there was an PHP core function which took two arrays as arguments:

```
$a = array('1', '3');
$b = array('1'=>'apples', '2'=>'oranges', '3'=>'kiwis');
```

And performs an intersection where the values from array `$a` are checked for collisions with the keys in array `$b`. Returning something like

```
array('1'=>'apples', '3'=>'kiwis');
```

Does such a function exist (which I missed in the documentation), or is there a very optimized way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try using array_flip {switches keys with their values} and then use array_intersect()
on your example :

```
$c = array_flip($b); // so you have your original b-array
$intersect = array_intersect($a,c);
```

Comment: This would work for the given example, but does not allow for duplicate values in $b. I'd do the variation of flipping $a (as it is supposed to hold keys anyway) and do `array_intersect_key($b, array_flip($a))`.

Comment: `array_intersect_key($b, array_flip($a))` turns out to do the job. Cheers!

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of array_flip. Did the job great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear what you want. Do you want to check values from $a against KEYS from $b?

There's a few intersect functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

But possibly you need:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-ukey.php so that you can define your own function for matching keys and/or values.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple `foreach` to iterate the first array and get the corresponding values from the second array:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($a as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $b)) {
        $output[$key] = $b[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation of the Gumbo answer, should be more efficient as the tests on the keys are performed just before entering the loop.

```
$intersection = array_intersect($a, array_keys($b));
$result=array();
foreach ($intersection as $key) {
    $result[$k]=$b[$k];
}
```